# install two hsqldb databases in jboss eap 6.1

Tags: database, jboss, hsqldb

I have installed JBoss EAP 6.1 that comes with a default HSQLDB 1.3.x database and what I intend is to install a second HSQLDB 1.8.x database in the same app server.

In case of it should be possible how do I must to do to configure them?

Best regards,

Thanks,
oggie0563

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new database using the default HSQLDB jar that comes with JBoss.

You can also replace the HSQLDB jar that is in JBoss with HSQLDB version 2.3.1 and create new databases.